# MyBatis Batch Insert/Update Using Annotations

Tags: mybatis, ibatis, spring-mybatis

Please let me know, how to perform batch insert/update in mybatis using annotated mappers.

Answer (score 9):

you can do it like [this](https://github.com/hbhd/springmvc-mybatis-generator-test/blob/1bb947d171ca38eed93a3cd7a962156ef78373a1/mybatis-test/src/main/java/test/dao/MybatisDemoDAO.java):

```
@Insert({
            "<script>",
            "insert into mybatis_demo (name, age)",
            "values ",
            "<foreach  collection='dmoList' item='dmo' separator=','>",
            "( #{dmo.name,jdbcType=VARCHAR}, #{dmo.age,jdbcType=INTEGER})",
            "</foreach>",
            "</script>"
    })
    int insertBatch(@Param("dmoList") List<MybatisDemoDMO> dmoList);
```

Answer (score 2):

do in simple way

```
@Insert({"<script>", 
        "insert into  user_master (first_name,last_name) values ",
        "<foreach collection='userList' item='user' index='index' open='(' separator = '),(' close=')' >#{user.first_name},#{user.last_name}</foreach>",
        "</script>"})
    int insertUserList(@Param("userList") List<UserNew> userList);
```

It's work perfect for me and i inserted bulk record in my PostgreSQL database using above single insert.